# How to enable fully pyzmq auto suggestion in Pycharm IDE?

Tags: python, ide, pycharm, zeromq, pyzmq

I'm using the `pyzmq` library.

In some cases in `pyzmq` there is not auto-suggestion in Pycharm IDE.

---

For example, when I use `Pycharm` IDE I can't access to, many of ZMQ constant variable and etc as auto-suggestion. Only some classes are auto suggestable:

```
import zmq

zmq.SUB  # I can't get it with auto-suggestion.
zmq.EAGAIN  # I can't get it with auto-suggestion.
zmq.Contex()  # I can to access it using auto-suggestion.
```

---

However, when I used the `IPython` I can do that:

```
import zmq

zmq.SUB
zmq.PUB
zmq.DEALER
zmq.EAGAIN
zmq.CONFLATE
zmq.Contex()
.
.
.
```

Comment: Seems like constants are defined dynamically or in some other way that is not supported in PyCharm's static code analysis

Comment: Looks like there is a feature request for this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-27715